# insertion sort in a linked list

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I am trying to understand this piece of code which basically performs insertion sort on a linked list.
I am lost in this step.

```
cur->next = prev->next;
```

What is the role of this step?

```
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* insertionSortList(ListNode* head) {
        ListNode* dummy = new ListNode();
        ListNode* prev = dummy ;
        ListNode* cur = head ;
        ListNode* next;
        
        while(cur!=NULL){
            next = cur->next ;
            while(prev->next!=NULL && prev->next->val <cur->val){
                prev = prev->next;
            }
            cout<<"prev->next is "<<prev->next<<endl;
            if(prev->next){
                cout<<"val is "<<prev->next->val <<endl;
            }
            cur->next = prev->next;
            prev->next = cur;
            
            prev = dummy ;
            cur = next;
        }
        return dummy->next ;
    }
};
```

Comment: Try drawing it on a paper and it will become clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That and the following line work together to insert `cur` between `prev` and `prev->next`.

```
cur->next = prev->next;
prev->next = cur;
```

Before:

```
prev -------.
            V    
   dummy -> 4 -> 8 -> 10 

cur --------.
            V    
            6 -> 3 -> 16 -> ...
                 ^
next ------------'
```

After `cur->next = prev->next`:

```
prev -------.
            V    
   dummy -> 4 -> 8 -> 10
                 ^
cur --------.   /
            V  /  
            6-/  3 -> 16 -> ...
                 ^
next ------------'
```

After `prev->next = cur` and `cur = next`:

```
prev -------.
            V    
   dummy -> 4    8 -> 10 
            |    ^
            |   /
            V  /  
            6-/  3 -> 16 -> ...
                 ^
next, cur -------'
```

So the list is now `4 -> 6 -> 8`. `next` existed to allow the next step to work.